# Updating environment variable in a shell script

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables

I am trying to update the value of an environment variable in a third party shell script. My OS is Oracle Linux Server release 6.4 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago).

I already have the below environment variables defined in `/etc/bashrc` (for all users)

```
JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_45
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin

export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

I would like to use a different jdk installation for one of the shell script. Hence I add the below lines to `customscript.sh`

```
JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_79
export JAVA_HOME
echo "PATH variable is $PATH"
...                      #other script code
```

The customscript.sh still defaults to the old environment variable value for the `PATH` variable. The output of the above echo command shows that it is still referring to the old `JAVA_HOME` variable value.

What could I be missing?

Comment: You are echoing PATH, but changing JAVA_HOME - is that what is intended ?  EDIT -> I get it now, you are changing PATH based on JAVA_HOME earlier - so the variable is substituted in the PATH already. PATH will not change now if you change JAVA_HOME.   To change PATH - you have to write the PATH setting line again in your script after changing the JAVA_HOME

Comment: Amit is on the right path; your /etc/bashrc sets PATH by interpreting $JAVA_HOME's value at that moment. It does not get re-interpreted if JAVA_HOME changes later. You'll want to ad a line to the 3rd-party shell script that reads `PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH` so that the 1.7 JAVA_HOME is put into the path before the /etc/bashrc's 1.8 JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Cool. It works. Thanks for the quick help. Please add it as an answer. I will accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `/etc/bashrc` sets `PATH` by interpreting `$JAVA_HOME`'s value at that moment. It does not get re-interpreted if `JAVA_HOME` changes later. You'll want to add a line to the 3rd-party shell script that says: `PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH` so that the 1.7 `JAVA_HOME` is put into the path before the `/etc/bashrc`'s 1.8 `JAVA_HOME`.